# Safari on iPhone and iPad crashes while zooming (double-tap and pinch)

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I have a problem with a Wordpress-run website: http://www.igorlipinski.com - Safari freezes and eventually crashes on iOS devices while using the zoom option, either double tap or pinch to zoom option. It looks and works very well on desktop browsers. I can't quite locate the problem... any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I disabled javascript on my iPhone and the site worked beautifully, so at least I know where to look now! I would appreciate if anyone had a direct solution for this particular site, but I will work on it in the meantime.

Comment: I suspect it might be due to one of the plugins used on the site.
Have you tried it on any other browsers on your iPhone/iPad?

Comment: I tried it on Opera Mini and the zoom problem disappears (it doesn't look great on it, but I can live with it for the time being). I will try out disabling different plugins and see if it works. Thanks! By the way, I'm using popular theme on themeforest called Equilibrium, but it seems like it's not optimized for Safari mobile, which is a shame, let me know if you have any other thoughts or solutions.

Comment: Did you figure out what the culprit was? I'm running into something similar, where zooming into our site causes image memory usage to skyrocket and crash the browser; however turning off JS fixes it. We use a lot of JS so figuring out where to start in terms of disabling things is tricky.

Comment: I have analysed the crash report about similar crash, It says "The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0: needs to be moved to a background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block the main thread"

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar kind of issue. Found issue with **canvas** drawing.
Basically there is one issue with canvas drawing. when we draw or erase something using canvas's methods like drawRect(), lineTo(), moveTo(), etc... it will create extra layer (like pixels on canvas) which causes memory leakage issue in safari browser for ipads/mobiles.

I am still looking for solution/alternative for memory leakage while using canvas.

Hope this will help you find any clue related to your project.